# How to convert price format string into number in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, number-formatting, data-conversion

I have a string like this

> "$2,099,585.43"

"$" maybe any symbol, like @,#..etc.

I want to convert this into 2099585.43

Is there any simple way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use **[`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)** and remove characters which are not a digit or dot.

```js
console.log(
  "$2,099,585.43".replace(/[^\d.]/g, '')
)
```

Comment: @ManikandanRam : glad to help